# Manipulate ListPlot and Sliders

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to `Manipulate` with a Slider a `ListPlot`.

Here is the code:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Range[a]], {{a, 15}, 1, 1, 15, 1, Slider}]
```

The `Manipulate` doesn't accept a Slider as control option:

```
"ControlType -> Slider is not supported for the variable specification "a$$, 1, 1, 15, 1". ControlType -> InputField will be used instead.
```

How can I use a Slider with this `Manipulate`?

Comment: use `{{a, 15}, 1, 15, 1, Slider}` (or `{{a, 15}, 1, 15, 1}`) instead of `{{a, 15}, 1, 1, 15, 1, Slider}`?

Comment: `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Range[a], PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 15}}], {{a, 3}, 1, 15, 
  1}]` ?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you expected the control specification `{{a, 15}, 1, 1, 15, 1, Slider}` to do. I just double-checked the documentation and I don't see this syntax there. `{{a, 15}, 1, 15, 1}` works, and is documented. So is `{{a, 15}, 1, 15, 1, Slider}`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple implement

```
{Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 100, 1}], Dynamic@ListPlot[Range[n]]}
```